# Android Studio SVN 1.8 This client is too old to work with the working copy

Tags: android, svn, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Hoping someone can help with this...

I downloaded SmartSVN and opened a working copy (Android project) in it. It asked me to upgrade the working copy to 1.8.

This causes me no problems while using the svn client. However I did need to upgrade my command line svn client (Running OSX Yosemite).

Now when I type svn --version on the command line it is pointing at version 1.8... Bonus!

However, in Android Studio, when I run assembleProductionRelease, I have a stage which runs svn info and extras the revision number.

This is the code

```
def getSvnRevision() {
    new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
        def result = exec {
            executable = 'svn'
            args = ['info']
            standardOutput = os
        }
        def outputAsString = os.toString()
        def matchLastChangedRev = outputAsString =~ /Last Changed Rev: (\d+)/
        return "${matchLastChangedRev[0][1]}"
    }
}
```

This doesn't run anymore and reports;

svn: E155021: This client is too old to work with the working copy at xxx

EDIT
I have also amended the path in Preferences -> Version Control -> Subversion which is called 'Use command line client' to point at the svn file in the correct path.

I have also invalidated cache in Android studio to see if that helped, still no luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is default SVN of Android Studio in Mac, that locate at `/usr/bin/svn`. Until now, it still version `1.7`, but most of SVN client (such as SmartSVN) use `1.8` that locate at `/usr/local/bin/svn`.

To fix for your Android Studio, you can change from `Preferences -> Version Control -> Subversion` and set the path `/usr/local/bin/svn`.

To make sure which SVN is chosen by your command line, just type `which svn`, it will show full path of `svn` command is pointed to. You should change to there.

Hope this help.

**Update 04/19/2016**

I share screenshot: [image: Path in Android Studio]

Comment: This was the solution for me! I noticed when using svn in the terminal everything went fine, but still Android Studio couldn't solve the issues. After changing it in the preferences like described above, everything went smooth.

Comment: BTW: It could be that you need to change the 'Use command line client' also to the full path.

Comment: What do you mean by **set the path**?  There is no path setting in Version Control window.

Comment: I took screenshot, please check it... Sorry because I use the word is not correct.

Comment: Woking for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

After Hours of searches I've finally found a solution for Mac OsX (I've got Yosemite, but I think it's the same for other versions of OSx).

It's all explained in this link: http://andowebsit.es/blog/noteslog.com/post/how-to-upgrade-subversion-on-osx/

**Edit:** here the solution in case the link expires

First, you have to be sure that the installed version of the SVN Client is 1.8 using **svn --version**. The result should be similar to this:

> svn --version
>   svn, version 1.8.13 (r1667537)
>   compiled Jun  5 2015, 19:21:21 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0

If your svn version is not 1.8, use **brew** to install the new version of subversion.

Then in order to get the correct path of the svn executable you have to use the **which** command:

> which -a svn
>   /usr/bin/svn
>   /usr/local/bin/svn

Finally go to Android Studio *Preferences* -> *Version Control* -> *Subversion* and put the **/usr/local/bin/svn** string in the *Use command line client* option.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged because links can expire

Answer (score 0):

1. Try updating your SVN version - download latest version of SVN and install it. In Options, set SVN path to this new versions's bin directory(or wherever svn executable is). This should resolve this issue.
2. If not resolved,  See the "Event Log" or "Terminal window". You see something like "svn version mismatch" - Fix now. Click on fix now. This will either fix issue or it will open a left hand side panel, that has link to upgrading project settings.

Answer (score 0):

**Make AndroidStudio use it's internal SVN client.**

For me this happened (on Windows) when I installed a new version of my svn client (TortoiseSVN).

If you don't want to update your working copy to a newer version, you have to make AndroidStudio to use it's internal SVN client, which can be done in *File > Settings > Version Control > Subversion* by unticking the checkbox of the '*Use command line client*' option.

Answer (score 0):

To change the format of the local working copy, do the following:

Open the **Version Control Tool** window by doing one of the following:
On the main menu, choose **View | Tool Windows | Version Control**.
Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>.
Switch to the Subversion Working Copies Information tab.
This tab is only available, when the current project sources are entirely or partially under Subversion control.

Scroll to the information on the required directory and click the Change link.
Note that Subversion 1.9 can be used with the local working copy version 1.8, so in this case the Change link will not appear.

In the **Convert Working Copy Format** dialog box, that opens, select the desired format option.